# how can I download urls with these requirements?

Tags: download

I want to download a list of urls from a website that I have a login and it gets logged in via a form (I suppose it uses a cookie to authenticate).

How can I load the text of urls to a program and have it download them for me, using the cookie from the web browser?

Also, I need to wait a delay between each downloading of url, so that it won't abuse the server, preferably random delay if possible.

Can you tell me please how to do that? I am looking for a freeware preferably

Thanks!

EDIT:
    I just need a download manager that I will load a list of urls and it will download them using the cookie from web browser!

```
I just want it to delay few seconds between each download!
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option for automating downloads as a non-programmer is to use a so-called *web browser macro recorder* like [iMacros for Firefox](http://imacros.net) or [Kantu (Chromium)](https://kantu.io). Both options are free. And both have a "Wait" command that you can use for delays.

Since these recorders automate the web browser itself, they also take care of cookies etc (unlike, for example, the cURL command line tool).

Comment: are you sure I need to create a macro? I already have the url list and there are tons of download managers that can use cookies!

Comment: Hmm... can download managers import CSV files (your URL list)? I don't think so. Also, I am not sure if they can create the delays you need. The macro recorders can do all that.